# Ontario HST rebate: Would I be receiving a cheque if I owe Canada Revenue Agency (CRA)?

Tags: canada, ontario, hst, rebate, taxes-owing

Would I be receiving a cheque if I owe Canada Revenue Agency?

Answer (score 4):

I found an [answer at Canada Revenue Agency](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/bnfts/rltd_prgrms/fq_sttb-eng.html#q24) that addresses this directly.  Quote:

> **24. I have an outstanding debt with the CRA and didn't receive my GST
>   credit because I owed money to the
>   government. Will I receive my OSTTB
>   payment?**
>
> ***Yes.** The OSTTB payment cannot be applied against other debts, such as
>   outstanding income tax payable. If you
>   are entitled to an OSTTB payment, you
>   will receive it.*
>
> However, if you are reassessed and it
>   is found that you received a payment
>   that you were not entitled to receive,
>   or you received more than you were
>   entitled to receive, you must pay back
>   that amount or the amount will be
>   deducted from future entitlements.
>
> Similarly, if you are reassessed and
>   it is found that you received a lower
>   payment than you are entitled to
>   receive, you would be issued the
>   additional amount.
>
> *[emphasis mine]*

Answer (score 0):

So far everyone I know has received their cheques and I know that I owe on my 2009 income tax.  Something tells me I am not going to receive my HST cheque.

Comment: Speculation.  Read the link above from Canada Revenue Agency.