# We received the first HST payment but we got a notice of an error. Will we still get our next HST payment?

Tags: canada, hst, ontario, taxes-owing

We received the first HST payment.  However, something was wrong on our taxes.  We got a notice a week or so ago saying that we now owe, because our rent receipts  -- that we handed in -- got lost.  So, now they say we paid no rent all of 2009 (big mistake on their part since we paid our rent and shouldn't be owing any money).

Will we still get our next payment of HST even though they say we owe money on taxes now?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. I expect you will need to get your rent receipt problem sorted out first before you receive another rebate.

You kept a copy of your receipts, I hope?  Better yet, you should keep the originals and only send in copies.

Comment: We only sent in copies ... well H&R made copies and did all the work for us.

Answer (score 1):

Ether makes a good point on always keeping a copy of the receipts you send in.

However, you likely **will** receive your OSTTB cheque, even with the outstanding debt to CRA.  While in your case the debt arose due to a filing error, fundamentally the issue is the same as if you had owed money to begin with.  Refer to this other question:  [Ontario HST rebate: Would I be receiving a cheque if I owe Canada Revenue Agency (CRA)?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1747/ontario-hst-rebate-would-i-be-receiving-a-cheque-if-i-owe-canada-revenue-agency)  Notably:

> **24. I have an outstanding debt with the CRA and didn't receive my GST
>   credit because I owed money to the
>   government. Will I receive my OSTTB
>   payment?**
>
> ***Yes.*** The OSTTB payment cannot be applied against other debts, such as
>   outstanding income tax payable. If you
>   are entitled to an OSTTB payment, you
>   will receive it.  [...]  [*(source)*](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/bnfts/rltd_prgrms/fq_sttb-eng.html#q24)

Comment: We hadn't owed any money on taxes beforehand. We only sent in the copies for our rent reciepts we still have the originals.

Comment: @Sara Send in another copy of your receipts, then.  That should restore your refund to what it was originally.  Just because CRA lost its copy of your receipts doesn't mean you're not entitled to the deduction.  Either way, though, I don't think your entitlement to the HST rebate is affected.